# Taylor polynomial of degree $3$ around the point $0$ using the series expansion

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, taylor-expansion

I want to calculate the Taylor polynomial of degree $3$ around the point $0$ for the function $f(x)=\tan (x)\cdot \log (1+2x)$ using the series expansion.

We have that $\tan (x)=x+\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{2x^5}{15}+\ldots $ and $\log (1+2x)=2x-2x^2+\frac{8x^3}{3}-4x^4+\ldots$.

So is the Taylor polynomial of degree $3$ for $f(x)$ equal to $x\cdot (2x-2x^2)=2x^2-2x^3$ ?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: For the functions $\tan (x)$ and $\log (1+2x)$ we need the Taylor polynomial of degree $2$, right? So that the product is at most of degree $3$, right? @Bernard

Comment: Yes,that's right, because the Taylor expansions of these functions have  order $1$ (in the sense of power series).

Comment: Great!! Thank you!! :-) @Bernard